# Lengthy HTTP calls failing in TaskPane apps on Office for Mac Client

Tags: macos, office365, office-js, excel-addins

We have built an Excel Task Pane add-in that interacts with our server to get data from an external source. For few calls the server takes more than a minute to respond. For such calls, Excel add-in (which runs in Mac Desktop Excel 2016) doesn't receive any response (either success or failure or timeout) even though the server has sent it.

Note: This happens only when the add-in runs in Mac Desktop Excel. In other systems and browsers it works fine.

Does the Office for Mac client have a low timeout threshold? If so, is there a way to increase it?
Is there any other workaround for this?

Comment: Can you try to reformat the question without linking to personal cloud stuff. Stackoverflow can't rely on your personal documents.

Comment: If you try the same code in Safari, what happens there?  Let's isolate whether it's an Add-in or Mac browser issue.

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky tested on Mac safari, it works fine without timeouts.

Comment: The issue is demonstrated in a sample app here: https://1drv.ms/f/s!AkR0pKvDAOt3gQTvH39FVVwfrLlh

In this app, request to server can be made by clicking on the button "Make request to server". The server waits for 73800ms and then responds. But the client running in Mac doesn't receive it.

Comment: OK.  Let me report the issue to the team, and see if someone can get back to you.

Comment: @bibi updated the question as requested.

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

The WebKit control that we use to host the add-in does not provide a way for us to override the default timeout for web requests. The default timeout is 60 seconds on Mac. If you need to have a request longer than 60 seconds I have verified that WebKit respects the XMLHttpRequest's timeout property on OSX 10.11.5. This request will not timeout for 120 seconds:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var startDate = new Date();
xhr.open('GET', url, true);

xhr.timeout = 120000; // time in milliseconds

xhr.onload = function () {
  console.log((new Date() - startDate) + " milliseconds to return.");
};

xhr.ontimeout = function (e) {
  console.error("error");
};

xhr.send(null);
```

Note that this is not working starting in mac OS Sierra 10.12.1. There seems to have been a regression in WebKit. A tracking bug is opened here: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=163814.

Comment: We waited for the bug to be marked resolved and retested once it was marked fixed. We are seeing this again on 10.11.16  The bug is marked as fixed but, it doesn't seem to apply to the version I'm testing (10.11.6)

Comment: I see it is included in https://trac.webkit.org/browser/branches/safari-602.3.12.0-branch which was released on December 13. 10.11.6 was released before the fix was checked-in. Could you update to a later version and try?

Comment: Tested it on 10.12.3 The issue still exists. ( I have set the timeout property to 90 seconds in client and server sends the response in 80 seconds. The client however doesn't receive it and also the error callback is not called after 90 seconds. It just waits indefinitely.) Let me know if this version (10.12.3) had the fix.

Comment: I verified that the above code with macOS 10.12.3 and Safari 10.0.3(12602.4.8) when the web request takes 80 seconds. I have not seen any issues with xhr.ontimeout not getting called after the timeout I specify. Can you host a repro somewhere?

Comment: Dan, this is still reproducing with macOS 10.12.6. Can you provide an email through which we can communicate further and show you how its reproducing? Thanks