# Excel for Mac JS Add-in HTTP Request Timeout

Tags: javascript, excel, office365, office-js

I'm working on an Excel js add-in. The add-in has multiple rest api calls using ajax. One in particular can take some time to respond (in this case over 10 minutes). It is working properly in Excel Online - the response is received and displayed. Excel for Mac appears to have a timeout (or something) affecting the request after 1 minute. It's returning a status code 0 and our server is throwing a 499 (client cancelled request).

Is there a timeout in Office for Mac and, if so, is there a way to change it? Adding a timeout field to the ajax request isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the same question as [Lengthy HTTP calls failing in TaskPane apps on Office for Mac Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39617221/lengthy-http-calls-failing-in-taskpane-apps-on-office-for-mac-client/40224845). There is a default timeout of 60 seconds for the WebKit control Office uses. There is no way to override the default timeout from our end. I have tried the following code that works with a 10 minute request:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var startDate = new Date();
xhr.open('POST', url, true);

xhr.timeout = 800000; // time in milliseconds

xhr.onload = function () {
  console.log((new Date() - startDate) + " milliseconds to return.");
};

xhr.ontimeout = function (e) {
  console.error("error");
};

xhr.send("data");
```

Note that there was a WebKit regression that is now fixed that broke setting the timeout property. You will need the latest version of Safari. Also, jQuery timeout property wasn't working because they are not actually setting the native XMLHttpRequest::timeout property that WebKit listens to. If you are using a third party library to make the request, make sure it sets XMLHttpRequest timeout properly.